# Using OpenLayers, can I draw a line which goes West instead of East?

Tags: openlayers

In the attached code snippet, the start location for the line is [-82, 42] which is drawn headed East. But, I would like to be able to draw the line (shown in red) headed West, which would look like:

[image: headed west]
(the red line was hand drawn)

How can I do this with OpenLayers?

```js
let coordinates = [
  [-82, 42],
  [10, 45]
];
            
const myFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates),
  name: "Line"
});

myFeature.setStyle(
  new ol.style.Style({ stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: "green", width: 8 }) })
);

const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [myFeature]
});

const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [-50, 43.5],
    zoom: 1
  })
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.1.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.1.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: While you could simply add 360 degrees to negative longitudes that may not render correctly.  To solve that you would need to calculate the coordinates for a MultiLineString, see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/11681

Comment: You are correct, adjusting lon by 360 degrees did not render correctly. It did look like it was trying, but that is not supported.